# Hide sensitive HTTP Server Response in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, browser, http-headers, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I've been hacking my way through the internet for the past half hour looking for an answer to this issue. I want to build an online system for school testing running on nodejs. This apps front-end would request questions "and corresponding answers" from the backend and this information will be delivered to the front end. The whole purpose of this is that the app should calculate test scores instantly and display it.

Now, in the browsers network tab, we can see server responses, and if I were to build an app that submits both questions and answers, any student could just peep at the answers in the dev console and get perfect scores.

One way wouldve been to deliver the questions alone and then send back to the server to do the scoring and then send back the score but that doesnt feel "real-time".

**REQUEST INFORMATION IS VERY OK**

[image]

**NEED TO REMOVE RESPONSE FROM BEING DISPLAYED IN BROWSERS DEV CONSOLE**

[image]

So, how can I safely transport this information to the front end, but hide it from showing in the dev console headers response zone in a browser? Or any ideas on how I can implement this real-time concept without losing out on security.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't send the answers to the client, but do AJAX requests back to the server within the page to verify answers.

Comment: Sending the answer back to the server and then waiting for a response takes only a fraction of a second. That doesn't seem like a big problem. But if you feel that it is a problem you could try to encrypt the answer and decrypt it in the browser. That system could still be cracked though since the decryption key will have to be on the client and can be found by a student.

Comment: @Joe Will try. Thanks

Comment: @SpiderPig I am a dev in Nigeria, thats in Africa. The quality of internet around here isnt as good as yours and it might break...like literally!! DESTROY EVERYTHING!!! But I get the point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like serializing it to binary and when they send the answer deserialize it back and check for the answer. That way even if they look at the network tab the will only see binary they could not understand.